# Nvidia 820M GPU error on Dell Inspiron 3542

Tags: laptop, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

In my laptop, under device manager, The "NVIDIA GeForce 820M" is displayed with a yellow warning sign. When clicked, it says "Error 43...."

When I ran GPU-Z, the NVIDIA GeForce 820M is displayed but,

Memory Size is 0MB, 
GPU Clock is 0MHz,
BIOS Version is Unknown etc.

I installed the drivers several times with no luck. I tried also Ubuntu, but then also it didn't work.
When I opened the laptop, I saw the thermal paste was all over the GPU chip. Is the GPU fried or any hope of getting it fixed?

Comment: When you say the paste was "all over the GPU chip" this would be the natural state of affairs, unless more than the correct amount was applied at the previous junction & some has squeezed out. If you broke that junction, you must clean & re-apply fresh paste before powering the machine up again. If you did & still see the same null-data, assume the GPU is fried.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've turned the computer on without reapplying thermal paste. :(

Comment: Then send it to a repair shop, see what they say.